# Differentiate a rational function

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I'm having problems solving a problem. Suppose to find the slope of: 
$$f(x)= \frac{x}{x-2}$$ at the given point $(3,3)$.

I got $1/(1) = 1$ (for the slope)
But my answerbook says that it's $-2$. Can someone explain what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: $f$ is not a polynomial. It's a rational function, though. You probably misapplied the quotient rule.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Method one: 
$$f(x) = \frac{1}{h(x)} \ \to \ f'(x) = -\frac{h'(x)}{h^2(x)}$$
$$f(x) = \frac{x}{x-2} = \frac{x - 2 + 2}{x-2} = 1 + \frac{2}{x-2}$$
$$f'(x) = 0 - 2(x-2)^{-2}$$
$$f'(3) = -2$$
Method two: 
$$f(x) = \frac{g(x)}{h(x)} \ \to \ f'(x) = \frac{g'(x)h(x) - h'(x)g(x)}{h^2(x)}$$
$$f'(x) = \frac{1\cdot(x-2) - 1\cdot x}{(x-2)^2}$$
$$f'(3) = \frac{-2}{1^2} = -2$$

**Edit**:

I think the key here is to understand that if:
$$f(x) = \frac{g(x)}{h(x)} $$ Then $f'(x)$ **is not** simply:
 $$f'(x) = \frac{g'(x)}{h'(x)}$$

Comment: Thank you, I'm unfamiliar with the rule you applied in the first step. Is there a name for it so that I can google it up and read on it?

Comment: @user1692517 - added the actual "rule". I believe it's called the [Quotient Rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_rule)